# getting an error in go: func main is unused

Tags: go, program-entry-point

I have written a simple code in Go but I am getting a weird error. I have attached a screenshot of code and error.

```
error: func main is unused
```

Code:

```
package structs

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello Structs")
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: The `main` function is only called (by the startup code anyway) when it's in `package main`. Since this is `package structs`, it's unused, hence your error. Aside from that: never use `go run` (what, never? well, hardly ever)—it's just for toy examples.

Comment: func main belongs into package main ONLY.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/720999

Answer (score 24):

Change `package structs` to `package main`.

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Program_execution

> A complete program is created by linking a single, unimported package
> called the *main package* with all the packages it imports,
> transitively. **The main package must have package name `main` and declare
> a function `main` that takes no arguments and returns no value.**

---

Note that `func main is unused` by itself is not an error, it is just a report of an instance of unused code from the `go-staticcheck` linter. Unused functions are allowed by the Go compiler, but they will be, if I'm not mistaken, omitted from the output binary.